# How to avoid the nested loop?

Tags: java

I want to achieve the below nested forloop code in single loop. I don't care about the space time complexity. I tried using to achieve using the hashmap but problem is all the `assocaiteId` in the coveragelist will have same value, Thus everytime value get overridden for the same key in hashmap.

Below are the `CoverageDetail.java` and `PlanDetail.java` classes

```
public class CoverageDetail {
    private String AssociateId;
    private String coverageId;
    // getter and setter
    
}

public class PlanDetail{
    private String planCode;
    private String AssociateId;
    private String classCode;
    private String productCode;
    // getter and setters
}
```

**Sample Input:**(Note: `employeeCoverage.getCoverageDetailList` return the below List("coverageDetails") )

```
{
  "coverageDetails": [
    {
      "AssociateId": "54BAcd132121",
      //other fields
    },
    {
      "AssociateId": "Ba4BAcd132131",
      //other fields
    },
    {
      "AssociateId": "5BAC4B132121",
      //other fields
    }
  ]
}
```

```
for (CoverageDetail coverageDetail : employeeCoverage.getCoverageDetailList) {
            for (Plan plan : plans) {
                if (coverageDetail.getAssociateId().equals(plan.getAssocaiteId())) {
                    coverageDetail.setClasscode(plan.getClasscode());
                    if (coverageDetail.getCoverageId().equals(plan.getproductcode())) {
                        coverageDetail.setPlancode(plan.getplanCode());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: `employeeCoverage.getCoverageDetailList()` will return many `CoverageDetail` Object all of them have will have same value of `AssociateId` but differntValue for `CoverageId`

**Expected output:**
All the objecta ofCoverageDetail from the
`employeeCoverage.getCoverageDetailList` should contain additional parameters which is `classCode` and `planCode`.

**Sample Response:**

```
{
  "coverageDetails": [
    {
    "AssociateId": "54BAcd132121",
    "classCode":"001M",
    "coverageId":"LXB",
    "planCode":"OXB"

// some other fields as well
     },
    {
      "AssociateId": "54BAcd132121",
      "classCode":"BCC",
      "coverageId":"MXB",
      "planCode":"OCB"

// some other fields as well
      
    },
    {
      "AssociateId": "54BAcd132121",
      "classCode":"CX2",
      "coverageId":"CXL",
      "planCode":"DOZ"

// some other fields as well      
    }
    
  ]

}
```

PS Any hint or the sample code will be helpful.

Comment: Seems like you should _group_ your plans two times: once for associate IDs, and once for product codes. A group is simply a `Map<String, List<Plan>>` (assuming that the IDs and codes are simple strings).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Include the sample data you have before you run your source code and the result you want after you run your source code.

Comment: is there any relationship of `CoverageId`  to `plans`?

Comment: There is no use of `CoverageId` in the snippet. As long as you compare only associateIds `coverageDetail.getAssociateId().equals(plan.getAssocaiteId())` should be a map aproach totaly fine.

Comment: I have edited the code. can you please look now. @Progman.
IMP note: Mistake have corrected:
CoverageId is added by replacing the planCode.

Comment: can you look now @Eritrean. Just corrected.

Comment: @man123 The sample input is missing, we don't know with what values you are starting with. Please provide a working [mcve].

Comment: Added the sample input @progman

Comment: @man123 Your sample input does not show any values for `Plan` objects, also it does not show other related data like the matching `coverageId` field. It is also not clear why the first and third object have different plan details for the same associate id. Keep in mind that we don't see your code or your data, that's why you should add a MCVE to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a map of `Plan` `associateId` --> `Plan` object and then use that, within your loop. Like this:

```
Map<String, Plan> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Plan plan : plans) {
  map.put(plan.getAssociateId(),plan);
}

for (CoverageDetail coverageDetail : employeeCoverage.getCoverageDetailList) {
                if (map.containsKey(coverageDetail.getAssociateId())) {
                    Plan plan = map.get(coverageDetail.getAssociateId());
                    coverageDetail.setClasscode(plan.getClasscode());
                    if (coverageDetail.getplanCode().equals(plan.getproductcode())) {
                        coverageDetail.setPlancode(plan.getplanCode());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This assumes tha your `Plan` has different associateId.

Comment: I have explicitly mentioned that AssocaiteId will be same. So this won't work. Even in my question I have specially mentioned that try-out as well.

Comment: You have mentioned coverageDetails associateId is duplicate, not plan associateId